# Aggregating Kolmogrov Smirnov Test in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, kolmogorov-smirnov

Is there a way to apply the KS test from the `spark.mllib` library in pyspark using the groupBy clause or some method of aggregation?
For example, I have a dataframe `df` with columns `ID` and `RESULT` like so:

```
+-------+------+
|     ID|RESULT|
+-------+------+
|3648296|  2.73|
|3648296|  9.64|
|3648189|  0.03|
|3648189|  0.03|
|3648296|  2.51|
|3648189|  0.01|
|3648296|  1.75|
|3648296| 30.23|
|3648189|  0.02|
|3648189|  0.02|
|3648189|  0.02|
|3648296|  3.28|
|3648296| 32.55|
|3648296|  2.32|
|3648296| 34.58|
|3648296| 29.22|
|3648189|  0.02|
|3648296|  1.36|
|3648296|  1.64|
|3648296|  1.17|
+-------+------+
```

There are 2 `ID`s `3648296` and `3648189` and each of their corresponding `RESULT` values are in the order of a few hundred thousand.
Is it possible to apply a groupBy function like so:

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

normtest=df.groupBy('ID').Statistics.kolmogorovSmirnovTest(df.RESULT, "norm", 0, 1)
```

such that I get an output dataframe like:

```
+-------+---------+----------+
|     ID|p-value  |statistic |
+-------+---------+----------+
|3648296|some val | some val |
|3648189|some val | some val |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

is this possible?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No I havent, I had to drastically reduce my dataset and use pandas which kind of defeated the purpose. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I actually managed to craft a solution for this using binning. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by binning the data, then performing [Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm) on the binned data (i.e., histogram).
It won't produce the largest distance, but if your effective distribution is smooth, then the result should be close enough.

By bucketing the results, you ensure that only a limited number of items (the number of buckets) will be loaded into memory at a time.

First, we need to implement a histogram version of the kstest:

```py
import numpy as np

def hist_kstest(hist: np.array, bin_edges: np.array, cdf):
    i = hist.cumsum()
    n = i[-1]

    bin_right_edges = bin_edges[1:]
    cdf_vals = cdf(bin_right_edges)
    
    statistic = np.max([
        cdf_vals - (i-1) / n,
        i / n - cdf_vals
    ])
    pvalue = stats.distributions.kstwo.sf(statistic, n)
    return statistic, pvalue
```

Then use it as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
from pyspark.ml.feature import QuantileDiscretizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Choose the number of buckets. It depends on your memory
# availability and affects the accuracy of the test.
num_buckets = 1_000

# Choose the null hypothesis (H0)
h0_cdf = stats.norm(0, 1).cdf

# Bucket the result and get the buckets' edges
bucketizer = QuantileDiscretizer(
    numBuckets=num_buckets, inputCol='RESULT', outputCol='result_bucket'
).setHandleInvalid("keep").fit(df)
buckets = np.array(bucketizer.getSplits())

def kstest(key, pdf: pd.DataFrame):
    pdf.sort_values('result_bucket', inplace=True)
    hist = pdf['count'].to_numpy()
    # Some of the buckets might not appear in all the groups, so
    # we filter buckets that are not available.
    bin_edges = buckets[[0, *(pdf['result_bucket'].to_numpy() + 1)]]
    statistic, pvalue = hist_kstest(hist, bin_edges, h0_cdf)
    return pd.DataFrame([[*key, statistic, pvalue]])

df = bucketizer.transform(df).groupBy("ID", "result_bucket").agg(
    F.count("*").alias("count")
).groupby("ID").applyInPandas(kstest, "ID long, statistic double, pvalue double")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! It is interesting! So you are binning the data into  buckets and then converting each binned dataset into pandas dataframes and applying the KS test from scratch. Typically when you do the pandas conversion it dumps that dataset into the driver node. I wonder if this method would perform calculations in the distributed nodes itself. Perhaps if the memory of each node is large enough?

Comment: By bucketing the results, you ensure that only a limited number of items (the number of buckets) will be loaded into memory at a time.

Comment: Yeah, i think that is the way to go. 
I will test it out and reply set it as answer. Thanks again!